# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

Tags: scala, oracle11g

While executing insert and update command in oracle 11g I'm getting below error.

```
val stmt = con.createStatement()
//Insert
  val query1 = "insert into audit values('D','abc','T','01-NOV-18','Inprogress')"
stmt.executeUpdate(query1)
//Update
val query2 = "Update audit Set status='test' where where product= = 'D'"
stmt.executeUpdate(query2)
```

I'm getting below error

```
 //Error while updating record
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00936: missing expression

at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:195)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:1036)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1845)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1810)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:294)
at com.oracle.OracleConnection$.main(OracleConnection.scala:21)
at com.oracle.OracleConnection.main(OracleConnection.scala)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share your DDL.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `where` and two `=` in your update query.

```
val query2 = "Update audit Set status='test' where product='D'"
```